# How can I by pass anything that is a date or number?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I need to send emails automatically using google scripts. I need to send emails if I either don't have a barcode for a product or an order confirmation, or if don't have both. This script worked in my test spreadsheet:

```
function sendEmails() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Orders").activate();
  var lastRow = app.getLastRow();

  //Get Stored Email Subject
  var getBarcodeSubject = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var getConfSubject = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(3, 2).getValue();

  //Get Stored Email Template
  var getBarcodeEmail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var getConfEmail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template").getRange(3, 1).getValue();

  //Get Daily Email Quota
  var emailQuota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

  //Get the number of rows in google sheet and take one off for headings row
  var totalEmails = lastRow - 1;

  //Check there is enough emails in quota
  if(totalEmails > emailQuota){
    Browser.msgBox("You have " + emailQuota + " emails left today and you're trying to send " + totalEmails + ". The emails were not sent.");
  }else{
    for(var i = 2; i<=lastRow; i++){
      //loop through each row in spreadsheet and get corresponding email and name
      var currentEmail = app.getRange(i, 20).getValue();
     //check if there is an email available 
     if(currentEmail.match('@') === null){
      continue;
     }
     var currentName = app.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
     var barcode = app.getRange(i, 15).getValues();
     var orderCon = app.getRange(i, 11).getValues();

     //replace placeholder with the relative stored name
     var getBarcodeBody = getBarcodeEmail.replace("{Name}", currentName);
     var getConfBody = getConfEmail.replace("{Name}", currentName);

    //Check if barcodes are not currently there
    if(barcode.match("n")||barcode.match("N")){

      //MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, getBarcodeSubject, getBarcodeBody);
      Logger.log(getBarcodeBody);
    }else if(orderCon.match("n")||orderCon.match("N")){

     //MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, getConfSubject, getConfBody);
     Logger.log(getConfBody);
    }//close else if
  }//close for loop
 }Browser.msgBox("Emails have been sent!");//close else statement
}//close function
```

However, the spreadsheet that will be used in real world environment, contains dates in the columns where the barcode and order confirmation is held. This throws an error as it seems `.match()` doesn't like numbers or dates. I have tried the following to fix this, but it does not work either:

```
if(barcode !== 'n' || barcode !== 'N'){
   continue;
  }else if(orderCon !== 'n' || orderCon !== 'N'){
    continue;
  }else if(barcode == 'n' || barcode == 'N'){
    Logger.log(getBarcodeBody);
    //MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, getBarcodeSubject, getBarcodeBody);
  }else if(orderCon == 'n' || orderCon == 'N'){
    Logger.log(getConfBody);
    //MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, getConfSubject, getConfBody);
  }else{
    Browser.msgBox("There was an error!");
  }
```

How can I overcome this? Thanks!

**Update:** it seems the last `if` statement I tried is passing over everything.

Comment: @I'-'I You may be right, sorry

Comment: It does, thats my bad. I'm not fully familiar with all of javascripts functions and methods yet as I haven't got much real world experience yet! Thanks for your help. I had actually thought of converting it to a string but I thought that was too easy (lol)